# Algorithm to return true if object contains each element of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In the below method,

```
self.search = (obj, search) => {
...
```

the second argument, `search` is an **array of search strings**. The first is an object.

The algorithm is to be used in a `filter` method that returns `true` if an object contains any of the search strings.

```
self.search = (obj, search) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).some(k =>
    typeof obj[k] === 'object'
      ? self.search(obj[k], search)
      : search.some(v => String(obj[k]).includes(v))
  )
}
```

So, for example, given the following object:

```
{
  name: 'Peter',
  phone: {
    primary: 5556667777,
    mobile: 1112223333
  }
}
```

`self.search` would return true for the following values of the `search` argument:

- `['Pet']`
- `['Pet', '111']`
- `['Pet', 'asdf']`

**The Question**

How can `self.search` be changed to instead return true only if *each* element of the `search` array is contained by the object?

Essentially, `['Pet', 'asdf']` should return `false`.

**Update**

Replacing `some` with `every` does not work when the array of search strings is across levels.

```
// `['Pet']` correctly returns true
// `['Pet', '111']` returns false when it should return true
// `['Pet', 'asdf']` correctly returns false
self.search = (obj, search) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).some(k =>
    typeof obj[k] === 'object'
      ? self.search(obj[k], search)
      : search.every(v => String(obj[k]).toLowerCase().includes(v))
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `every()` instead of `some()`?

Comment: @KursadGulseven, Yes, see the update.

Comment: The values being searched must be a value of an object property or it can be a key too?

Comment: @AramilRey, it should only be a value of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your single search function and a meta seach for every single item of the array.

```js
var search = (obj, v) => Object.keys(obj).some(k => typeof obj[k] === 'object' ? search(obj[k], v) : obj[k].toString().includes(v)),
    findAll = (obj, array) => array.every(a => search(obj, a)),
    obj = { name: 'Peter', phone: { primary: 5556667777, mobile: 1112223333 } };

console.log(findAll(obj, ['Pet', '99']));   // false
console.log(findAll(obj, ['Pet']));         // true
console.log(findAll(obj, ['Pet', '111']));  // true
console.log(findAll(obj, ['Pet', 'asdf'])); // false
```